# Problema con require_once y el file path de mis archivos

Tags: php, html

tengo un pequeño problema, estoy ordenando mis páginas dentro de varias carpetas y ahora no me funcionan los require_once que utilizo, ya he intentando varios cambios  como agregar "../" y poner el camino desde el disco pero nada funciona.

Este es mi error que imprime

```
Warning: require_once(../MVC/models/clase_iconos.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\views\icons\icon_table.php on line 2
```

[image: Esta es la carpeta principal de mi proyecto]
[image: Esta es la ruta de las paginas y quiero llamar alos archivos que estan en la carpeta models]
Estoy intentando llamar a los controladores en las carpetas controllers y models desde las paginas que estan en:MVC/views/nombre_pagina/pagina

```
<?php
  require_once '../MVC/models/clase_iconos.php';
  //instanciar clase Profesor
  $instance = new Icono();
  //variable que apunta hacia la funciión listar dentro de la clase Profesor
  $icono = $instance->Listar();
?>
<?php require_once '../MVC/base/header.php'; ?>
<?php require_once '../MVC/base/aside.php'; ?>
```

Esos requir me marcan error

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Sera que faltan permisos?

Comment: Por favor agrega tu código

Comment: Listo! añadi mi rutas de archivo y los require_once con los que tengo problema

Comment: Puedes definir un directorio asi `define('__ROOT__', directorio(directorio(__FILE__)));
require_once(__ROOT__.'/class_iconos.php');`  o usar un inlcude y listo, porque si mal no recuerdo en para `require_once` debes escrbir la ruta completa del directorio, algo asi: `require_once('/var/www/public_html/class_iconos.php');`

Comment: Según entiendo de tu pregunta el primer código ejemplo estaría dentro de la página `MVC\views\icons\icon_table.php`, y el último código correspondería a un archivo, digamos `ejemplo.php`, que estaría en la ruta `MVC/views/nombre_pagina/pagina`. Favor de confirmar y aclarar cuál de estos dos serías ese último ejemplo:

1- `MVC/views/nombre_pagina/pagina/ejemplo.php`
2- `MVC/views/nombre_pagina/ejemplo.php`

Ya con eso redactaría una respuesta.

Comment: Te hago una pregunta, estos tampoco te funcionan? <?php require_once '../MVC/base/aside.php'; ?>

Comment: @franco hola si ya intente eso tambien pero nada funciona :/

Comment: MVC no seria el nombre de tu proyecto? Digamos 'localhost/MVC'.
Entonces considero que la ruta debería ser:  require_once '../models/clase_iconos.php';

Comment: @franco ya intente eso tambien, nada jala, la ruata de mis paginas es:  localhost/MVC/views/carpetas_paginas/icon_table.php  y la ruta de mis modelos es: localhost/MVC/models/clase_modelos.php

Comment: YA encontre la solución, solo tenia que ponerle otro ../  y al final mi require quedo asi: require_once '../../models/clase.php';

Comment: muestra imagen de dónde existe la clase clase_iconos.php porque en efecto no veo que exista

Comment: Si estas en esta ruta: "MVC\views\icons\icon_table.php" para llamar al archivo que estra dentro de "MVC/models/clase_iconos.php" deberías hacerlo así:
require_once '../../models/clase_iconos.php'